# Rails/Ruby - Very strange, undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass on show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I like to think I'm not a complete newbie to rails, but I cannot get a simple Show action to work. I'm baffled. Ruby 2.2.2p95, also tried it on my production build, Ruby 2.0.0p643, both Rails 4.2.1.

The model is Players. Players have 2 params, :name and :position. When I index Players, it works fine. But when I try and view the show.html.erb, I get the classic error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass.

The Players model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :team, through: :ownership
has_one :ownership

validates :name, presence: true
validates :position, presence: true

def last_name
self.name.split(' ')[1]
end
end
```

The method:

```
def show
@player = Player.find(params[:id])
end
```

For troubleshooting, I've reduced the show.html.erb to this:

```
 <%= render 'welcome/menu' %>

 <%= @player.name %>
```

A rake routes shows:

```
 player GET    /players/:id(.:format)           players#show
```

If I try and view the player with id 269, this what the log shows

```
 Started GET "/players/269" for ::1 at 2015-09-08 21:58:12 -0400
 Processing by PlayersController#show as HTML
 Parameters: {"id"=>"269"}
 Rendered welcome/_menu.html.erb (0.7ms)
 Rendered players/show.html.erb within layouts/application (5.7ms)
 Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

 ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
  2: 
  3: <%= render 'welcome/menu' %>
  4: 
  5: <%= @player.name %>
  6:      
 app/views/players/show.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_players_show_html_erb___175427692043794239_70253361597080'
```

What in the world am I missing here?

EDIT:

This is the important part of the index.html.erb view. It works fine:

```
   <% @players.each do |player| %>
   <tr>
   <td></td>
    <td><%= link_to player.name, player %></td>
    <td><%= player.position %></td>
    <td><%= player.id %>
```

Players Controller:

```
 class PlayersController < ApplicationController
 def index
 @players = Player.all.sort_by{ |x| [x.position, x.last_name] }
 end

 def not_picked
  @players = Player.all.select { |m| m.team == nil}.sort_by{ |x| [x.position, x.last_name] }
 end
 end

def show
 @player = Player.find(params[:id])
end

 private

 def player_params
 params.require(:player).permit(:name, :position)
 end
```

Comment: You say index works. Can you post the code? Also, try to create a Player on the console: `rails c` and then `player = Player.create({name: "Name", position: "position"})` and then access the name property: `player.name` and see if it works.

Comment: does that Player object exists in the first place? What's the output of `p @player` in your show action and `<%= @player %>` in the show.html.erb?

Comment: Added index view and controller method.

Comment: Can you post the entire controller? Also can you go in to the console and run 'Player.find(269)' and make sure that returns a record.

Comment: Sidenote: Your using ruby to sort after pulling records out of your database. Your much better off using ActiveRecord to do a database level order. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

Comment: you have an extra end after `not_picked` method, is that a typo ? coz if not , it literally ends the controller and your `show` method is just not called at all

Comment: Stewart, Player.find(269) returns the correct record. SELECT  "players".* FROM "players" WHERE "players"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 269]]
=> #<Player id: 269, name: "Sam Young", string: nil, position: "OT", created_at: "2015-09-09 01:12:21", updated_at: "2015-09-09 01:12:21">

Comment: Sameera207....you are right! I am SO embarrassed. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as correct. I am now going to go crawl under a rock and hide myself.

Comment: @SeattleDucati, :), done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an extra end after `not_picked` method, is that a typo? If not, it literally ends the controller and your show method is just not called at all.

Comment: Thank you Sameera! And thank you for not making fun of my foolishness:D

Comment: @SeattleDucati, its called `foolishness` now an after some time its called `experience` :D

Answer (score 1):

Because `find` method will return `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when record not found. So i guess the Player record is exist in your database.

I suggest you `p @player` after `@player = Player.find(params[:id])`, then do the same thing in the first line at `show.html.erb` to show what the `@player` is.

Maybe there is something change your `@player` to a `nil`.

Comment: if the id is not in the DB, as you say it will return `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. however at that point rails will blow up and will not render the view at all.

Answer (score 0):

You code looks fine, but my guess is something in your code making the @player variable `nil`

I would suggest the followings, steps with [pry debugger](https://github.com/pry/pry)

1 - a debugger after @player in controller

```
def show
  @player = Player.find(params[:id])
  binding.pry
end
```

check your code to see , if you get a `@player` object

2 - add a debugger to show view

```
<% binding.pry %>
<%= @player.name %>
```

and see if you still have the `@player`, by this you can understand when u r missing the value and work on that.

My guess is, some filter in controller might be wiping out your variable.